# Looping and finding empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on project in which I have to create a search engine through jQuery. Everything has been going great until I started looping through the array.

I don't know whether I'm doing it wrong, but for some reason, when I use a conditional it does not output the statement I want it to say. If I change the conditional to say whether there's something in the array output this, it does. But if the array is empty it does absolutely nothing. Why is that?

```js
for(var i = 0, j = response.length; i < j; i++){ 
    var searchItemRes = response[i];
    if(response.length === 0){
        $('' + '<ul>' +
            '<li><span>Nothing found, try again</span></li>' +
            '</ul>'
        ).appendTo(searchResults);
    }
    $('' + '<ul>' +
        '<li><img src="" /><span> '+searchItemRes.title+'</span></li>' +
        '</ul>'
    ).appendTo(searchResults);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can code that triggers on `response.length == 0` ever execute inside a loop that iterates `response.length` times?

Perhaps you meant:

```
if (response.length === 0) {
    $('<ul><li><span>Nothing found; try again</span></li></ul>').appendTo(searchResults);
}
else {
    for (var i = 0, j = response.length; i < j; i++) { 
        var searchItemRes = response[i];

        $('<ul>' +
            '<li><img src="" /><span>' + searchItemRes.title + '</span></li>' +
            '</ul>'
        ).appendTo(searchResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I meant. Thank you so much. I'm still in college learning how to do this and it's my first month into this course. Thanks so much again. :)!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
// declare local variables
var str, i, item;

// build the HTML source code string
if ( response.length === 0 ) {
    str = '<ul><li><span>Nothing found. Please, try again.</span></li></ul>';
} else {
    str = '<ul>';
    for ( i = 0; i < response.length; i += 1 ) {
        item = response[i];
        str += '<li><img src=""><span> ' + item.title + '</span></li>';
    }
    str += '</ul>';
}

// append the string to the DOM
$( searchResults ).append( str );
```

First off, declare the local variables at the top of the function. As you can see, my code uses 3 local variables.

Next, I doubt that you want to create one UL (list-holder) for each result. It makes more sense to have one UL element which contains all the results (which is what I've implemented in the above code).

Also, I recommend manipulating the DOM **only once** at the end - the live-DOM should be touched as few times as possible. Therefore, the above code builds the HTML source code string "off-DOM", and only in the end appends (the whole thing) to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0, j = response.length; i < j; i++){ 
    var searchItemRes = response[i];
    if (response.length === 0) {
        $('<ul><li><span>Nothing found, try again</span></li></ul>').appendTo(searchResults);
    }
    ...
}
```

That condition will never be executed. If `i = 0` and `j = response.length` and it's iterating `i < j` then it won't iterate at all if `response.length == 0` because `0 < 0` will just break out of the loop.

Comment: Metaphoric division is the wave of the future.